# override type choosing or compare two floats in php

Tags: php, comparison, compare

So basically, i'm getting two really really big ID's from different resources (external resource and database), and I need to compare them somehow. If they match, I need to break the action.

Seems simple enough, but PHP is converting them to floats (looks something like that 6.2983963148698E+14) and they never seem to match then.

What should I do? I tried googling for some type of a big integer in PHP, or casting them as strings. That did not work.

Bare in mind, I'm not really experienced at this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [BC Math functions?](http://www.php.net/bcmath)

Comment: I hate to spoil your 666 reputation, but +1

Comment: That's some really great functions, but I can't seem to get bccomp to work for me. It always says, that the left operand is larger, when in fact, it should be the opposite. For example: 651555829190656 is larger than 650384343310340, but bccomp tells me the opposite, when the ID's are converted into scientific floats. There's got to be a better way to compare these ID's.. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @donkapone Be sure to pass these numbers to the functions as STRINGS not as ints, i.e. `if (bccomp("651555829190656", "650384343310340")) {...}`  Use casts if necessary, i.e. `if (bccomp((string) $n, (string) $m)) {...}`  Dealing with large integers in PHP is more difficult than you might imagine when the numbers get large - the OS/hardware you're running on becomes important.  See this article (http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/integers-in-php-running-with-scissors-and-portability/) for more info.